# (Python) Query by dates that are stored as strings in mongoDB collection

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, nested, pymongo

**How can you query the db.collection by dates when the dates are stored as strings?** Since this database is large and growing, a for loop to convert each datetime does not make sense for a long term solution.

I am creating a pipeline to query a collection for any given dates, but every query I try results in an empty list [].

***date format:*** **"ts": "2018-09-26T21:02:19+00:00"**

I am looking for a solution that avoids reformmating the datetime key in a for loop because the database is growing, and it would take longer than running a non datetime query, converting to pandas then converting to datetime later downstream in the script.

I've tried several attempts from various SO posts and they produce empty results:
1.

```
n = db.collection.find({'ts':{'$lt':datetime.now(), '$gt':datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=10000)}})

print(n)
[]
```

2.:

```
start = datetime(2019, 2, 2, 6, 35, 6, 764)
end = datetime(2019, 2, 20, 6, 55, 3, 381)

doc = db.collection.find({'ts': {'$gte': start, '$lt': end}})
print(doc)
[]
```

However I am beginning to think it is how my date is formatted in the ts key. Here is an example of a document:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5babf3dab512dd0165efd36c"
},
"d": [
    {
        "d": [
            17317,
            16556,
            9680,
            55982,
            45948
        ],
        "h": 74.65,
        "ts": "2018-09-26T21:02:19+00:00",
        "p": [
            61,
            76,
            137,
            152,
            122
        ],
        "si": "9829563c95d0155f",
        "t": 24.82,
        "ti": "0000000000000000"
    },
    {
        "d": [
            17821,
            17488,
            9199,
            56447,
            44089
        ],
        "h": 80.09,
        "ts": "2018-09-26T21:02:19+00:00",
        "p": [
            61,
            76,
            137,
            152,
            122
        ],
        "si": "a42fbc88a44a316f",
        "t": 25.1,
        "ti": "0000000000000000"
    }
],
"gi": "GW-P1007"}
```

Am i missing something here? Is this a formatting problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can convert string to datetime and compare  them like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
q = list(db.collection.find())
result = []
for i in q:
    for j in i["d"]:
        time = datetime.strptime(j["ts"], "%Y-%m-%dT%X+00:00")
        end = datetime.now()
        start = end - timedelta(hours=10000)
        if time >= start and time <= end:
            result.append(i) #or append all document
```

As I see in your data, I think you should make a loop in "d" in your document but for convert and compare date you can do this.

you can convert datetime to string and do find like you want. Do this:

```
a = datetime.now()
now = a.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%X+00:00")
```

And now you can use find method.
for query in a array:

```
 db.collection.find( { "d": { $elemMatch: {"ts" : {'$lt':end, '$gt':start } } } )
```

Comment: Hi Ali thanks for the response. So, converting everything in the collection in a for loop would take much longer than just subsetting the data by another key -> then formatting to pandas dataframe -> converting to datetime then subsetting that way. Im doing this now and isnt a long term solution sense the database is growing. Is it possible to subset the collection by dates in the current ts format? I will edit the OP to provide more context. thanks.

Comment: i edited the OP to about solutions that do not involve converting everything to datetime. This method works, but is too slow for what i am looking for.

Comment: you can convert datetime to string like above.I think it will work faster.

Comment: It is giving a "KeyError: 'ts' ". Can you elaborate on a loop in "d" in the document?

Comment: Hey - now receiving a "KeyError: 'd'" - any idea on why?